# How do I validate .eslintrc.json files?

Tags: eslint

I'm running ESLint through the WebStorm editor. I apparently have an unexpected token in my `.eslintrc.json` file. However, WebStorm merely tells me that I have an unexpected token - not where it is.

How do I validate my `.eslintrc.json` file in a way that will reveal the line and column of the unexpected token?

This is my `.eslintrc.json` file (while you are welcome to tell me what's wrong, I would also like to learn how to validate it on my own):

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "sourceType": "script"
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"]
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  }
}
```

EDIT:

@Wayrex suggested that I rename the file to `.eslintrc`.
Having done so, I still get the error. This is a screenshot of the error:

[image: WebStorm complains about my .eslintrc file]

EDIT 2:

I asked JetBrains about their opinion, and they think the error message stems from ESLint having trouble parsing my source code, not my config file:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000094600--eslintrc-json-has-unexpected-token-

My ESLint is version 3.6.0

Comment: I see nothing wrong on your json structure, I've also validated it using https://jsonlint.com/
Could you try setting the configuration on a `.eslintc` file instead of a `.eslintrc.json`? (without the .json suffix)

Comment: @Wayrex thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question with the result of your suggestion.

Comment: Interesting.... Could you give us the version of Eslint you are using and if you are using it locally? Maybe a eslint reinstall might solve the problem...

Comment: @Wayrex It's a brand new install. I'm setting it up for the first time. The ESlint version is 3.6.0. I asked Jetbrains about their opinion, and they think the error message stems from ESlint having trouble parsing my source code, not my config file: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000094600--eslintrc-json-has-unexpected-token-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [this issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10549#issuecomment-401556232), Kevin Partington wrote:

> In ESLint 5.x, we don't support Node versions earlier than 6.14.0 (specifically, we support 6.14 or higher on the 6.x line, 8.10 or higher on the 8.x line, and 9.10 or higher). Please upgrade your version of the Node runtime or downgrade to ESLint 4.x. Thanks!

After upgrading node.js, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 14):

I know it may be too late but I had similar problem.
Although node version may be a key here, make sure to check **File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**.
Node interpreter should be set to proper version.
E.g. I am using nvm for all projects however for some reason Node interpreter was set to node 8. If you are using nvm make sure Node interpreter is like (~/.nvm/version/node//bin/node)

[image: Here how it would look like with nvm]